# How to model an ability to enhance other's abilities in Strange Fate?

Tags: character-creation, kerberos-club-fate, strange-fate

I'm planning a Misfits-style game using the rules from Kerberos Club Fate. I'm trying to figure out the best way to model a character whose power is the ability to drastically enhance other people's powers. I want this to work by actually increasing the power level of another power temporarily, but I'm not sure of the best way to model this as a skill. Would it just be a couple of Unusual modifiers?

Example:

Ryan has the skill "Laser Eyes" at a +2 Supernatural level. May has the "Enhance Power" skill. When May uses it and focuses on Ryan, she raises his skill based on how well she rolls. If she rolls poorly, she could raise it to a +3 or +4 as long as he uses it. If she rolls well, she could raise it to Ascendent or even Godlike levels.

Having it work only as she's focusing is easy enough. But other than aspects and fate points, I can't figure out how to enhance others.

Comment: Could you provide more information, and perhaps an example? A link to said game would be helpful, and so would an explanation of how you want it to work.

Comment: @InbarRose Answerers will need hands-on Strange Fate / Kerberos Club Fate experience to answer this, so I don't see the utility in adding a link to the game to the question.

Comment: @InbarRose I'll add a couple of examples, but I can't really link to the system, it's only available by buying it.

Comment: You should look at the [Teamwork](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/teamwork) Mechanics for Fate Core. And you can simply expand on that with a Stunt that might enhance the bonus, and/or provide it passively. Or a Fate-Powered Stunt that adds +2 to someone's power for the rest of the scene.. etc..... Should I make this an answer? (Using only Fate Core rules I don't know this Kerberos Club thing)

Comment: That's not really powerful enough for this. In Strange Fate, for each skill tier above the opponent, you replace a fudge die with a d6. So it's not just adding a +1 to a roll, or placing an aspect that can be tapped.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the basic mechanic Create Advantage (so using Enhance Power creates a "Chargin mah' Lazor" aspect with a bunch of free invokes). There are a few specific rule-breaking advantages you could add to the basic mechanic to model the player's focussed skill:

- Apply your peak skill to *any* skill in another player.
- Create more free invokes on success (so more efficiency/peak power)
- Relax rules about invoking aspects once-per-action so you can stack a whole bunch of fate points into a single action for maximum effectiveness.

You can probably find other rules to let the player break if you prefer.